# Count the number of bases of the vector space $\mathbb{C}^3$.

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics

**Problem:** Consider the set of all those vectors in $\mathbb{C}^3$ each of whose coordinates is either $0$ or $1$; how many different bases does this set contain?

In general, if $B$ is the set of all bases vectors then, 
$$B=\{(x_1,x_2,x_3),(y_1,y_2,y_3),(z_1,z_2,z_3)\}.$$

There are $8(6\cdot8+7)=440$ possible $B$s that contain unique elements with coordinates $0$ and $1.$ Now there is are $6\cdot 8+7$ sets that contain the element $(0,0,0)$, which makes the set $B$ linearly dependent and thus we are left with $385$ sets. Beyond this, I am finding it difficult to compute the final answer. Any hint/suggestion will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Knowing that none of x,y,z can be (0,0,0) there are only 7 choices for each.  Since they must be different you only have $\binom{7}{3}=35$ choices to make.

This is small enough to sort through by hand.

Comment: Additionally, it's not hard to show that three distinct non-zero $(0,1)$-vectors are linearly dependent iff they form a solution to $x+y=z$.

Answer (score 0):

The set contains 29 different bases out of 35 possible permutations (excluding the zero vector).
Here are the six elements of the set which do not form a basis:

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
(0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1) \\
(0, 0, 1), (1, 0, 0), (1, 0, 1) \\
(0, 0, 1), (1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1) \\
(0, 1, 0), (1, 0, 0), (1, 1, 0) \\
(0, 1, 0), (1, 0, 1), (1, 1, 1) \\
(0, 1, 1), (1, 0, 0), (1, 1, 1) \\
\end{eqnarray}
$$